# (Searching) Angular based Admin - Theme do configure our devices

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, themes

As i am completly new to Angular, i search for an advise.

My next project is to build a webapplication, which is running on BeagleBone boards. We deployed a software to the BeagleBone boards, which controls our sensors (that are connected to it). Our sensors generate count-data from people.

The webapplication is needet to send the system parameters to our software, which is listening to a specific port @ 127.0.0.1.

The goal is:

A user opens the angular based admin theme (which i am searching here)
A user runs through a install wizard for basic parameters (admin theme)
The webapp checks for incorrect inputs etc.
When saving those parameters (submitting simple forms) those parameters will be send to a specific port @ localhost
The devices gets the new parameters in real time and the configuration is finished
In the following some more informations:

We have a lot of devices. So i will develope on a single device, and after developing i just want to copy all of the contents to our different devices in production.
The BeagleBones to which our sensor are connected, do not have PHP installed. I get some sourcefiles from the previous developer (Angular)
Im new to Javascript/Angular. Bootstrap/HTML/CSS is not a problem for me. I also have experience at PHP/C/C++ which i can not use in this case.
There are not that much different templates needet, its more important that the setup/documentation and support ist good. A simple layout > than a heavy layout which is harder to understand.
If any further informations are needet, please post and i will try to answer as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Simple layout go for https://material.angular.io/components/categories

A lot of resources online for it [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/learning-material)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

But i am searching a layout. to which i can add the simple form components. But the design should already be finished. This way, i can save a lot of time.. there are themes for around 60$ on themeforest, i want to use one of this for basic layout (delete all components i dont need) and add the configurations. 

Are there any paid templates, which are simple and easy to understand? Thanks in advance.